# Erro de conexão com banco de dados .MDF C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, visual-studio, conexão

App.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\Sistema\Sistema.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Erro a seguir

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): O banco de dados 
'C:\SISTEMA\SISTEMA.MDF' não pode ser aberto porque sua versão é a 869.
 Este servidor suporta a versão 782 e anteriores. O caminho de desatualização não é suportado.
Não foi possível abrir o novo banco de dados 'C:\SISTEMA\SISTEMA.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE foi anulado.
Falha na tentativa de anexar um banco de dados autodenominado no arquivo F:\Sisgemp\Sisgemp.mdf. Existe um banco de dados com o mesmo nome, o arquivo especificado não pode ser aberto, ou está localizado em um compartilhamento UNC.
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   em WindowsFormsApp1.formLogin.acessar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:\Sisgemp\formLogin.cs:linha 50
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
ClientConnectionId:5f545993-bd51-42bf-870b-e3af757265b7
Error Number:948,State:1,Class:20
```

Comment: A versão 782 é um arquivo de banco de dados do Sql Server 2014, versão 706 é um arquivo de banco de dados do Sql Server 2012, parece que você está tentando um banco de dados de uma versão mais recente do arquivo de banco de dados (SQL Server 2014) para uma versão mais antiga (SQL Serevr 2012 Express). Pelo que sei, o SQL Server 2012 LocalDB não poderá mais usar esses bancos de dados já atualizados para o SQL Server 2014 LocalDB.

Referência: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e2c4003-f203-4d4b-8d30-46543700c3bb/visual-studio-server-explorer-error-version-782?forum=linqtosql

Comment: Era isso mesmo, eu desinstalei o 2012 e instalei o 2014 e funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versão do Sql Server, troquei do 2012 para 2014 e funcionou, também fuz um ajuste na conexão de LocalDB para .\SQLExpress

Answer (score 0):

A versão 782 é um arquivo de banco de dados do Sql Server 2014, versão 706 é um arquivo de banco de dados do Sql Server 2012, parece que você está tentando um banco de dados de uma versão mais recente do arquivo de banco de dados (SQL Server 2014) para uma versão mais antiga (SQL Serevr 2012 Express). Pelo que sei, o SQL Server 2012 LocalDB não poderá mais usar esses bancos de dados já atualizados para o SQL Server 2014 LocalDB.

Referência: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e2c4003-f203-4d4b-8d30-46543700c3bb/visual-studio-server-explorer-error-version-782?forum=linqtosql